framer motion path length animation not working in safari
i have an svg path length animation with framer motion and nextjs, the animation works perfectly fine in both firefox and chrome but does not work on safari
is there is any way to fix this issue ? or perhaps other ways to draw the svg
svg component
'use client';

import { motion, useInView } from 'motion/react';
import { useRef } from 'react';

interface AnimatedPathProps {
  d: string;
  stroke: string;
  width?: string;
  viewBox?: string;
}

const AnimatedPath: React.FC<AnimatedPathProps> = ({
  d,
  stroke,
  width,
  viewBox,
}) => {
  const container = useRef(null);
  const isInView = useInView(container, { once: true });

  return (
    <svg
      width={width}
      viewBox={viewBox}
      fill="none"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
      <motion.path
        ref={container}
        initial={{ pathLength: 0 }}
        animate={isInView ? { pathLength: 1 } : { pathLength: 0 }}
        transition={{ duration: 2, ease: 'easeOut' }}
        d={d}
        stroke={stroke}
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default AnimatedPath;

on my page
'use client';

import AnimatedPath from '@/components/elements/svg';

const Illustrations = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="pointer-events-none absolute left-0 top-0 w-[130rem]">
        <AnimatedPath
          d="M578.342 1C741.676 137 914 565 500.342 793C319 892.952 -23.2578 971 2.34224 843C34.3422 683 492.342 485 818.342 459C1079.14 438.2 1234.34 469 1382.34 565"
          stroke="#212121"
          width="100%"
          viewBox="0 0 1383 911"
        />
      </div>
      <div className="pointer-events-none absolute right-0 top-1/2 w-[50rem]">
        <AnimatedPath
          d="M1 1C8.33333 114 1 301 238 454C410 545.2 435.667 416.667 427 341C403 221 338.8 3.2 274 92C193 203 419 581 500 507"
          stroke="#212121"
          width="100%"
          viewBox="0 0 501 518"
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Illustrations;

I have check on caniuse and it does seem that path length is supported on safari as well

caniuse says no for Safari when I check it.

@RobertLongson you are correct i check the wrong element
SVGGeometryElement API: pathLength
so is there is any other way to animate this svg ?
they are simple svgs just lines and i want to draw them no fancy animations what so ever

You'd need to use SMIL.
